# Not able to reference a SKSpriteNode from Scene Editor to code

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, sprite-kit

I have created a `GameScene.sks` file, added a Colour Sprite, given it a name `dino`. Then in the `GameViewController`,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
    let skView = view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

I have `GameScene.swift` which looks like

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    //let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "dino-left")
    private var dino: SKSpriteNode? = SKSpriteNode()
    private var dinoWalkingFrames: [SKTexture] = []

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.backgroundColor = NSColor.white
        if let someDino = self.childNode(withName: "dino") as? SKSpriteNode {
            // ... does not works -->
            dino = someDino
            dino?.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
            print("Worked")
        } else {
            initDino()  // --> this works
            initBackground()
        }
    }

    func initDino() {
        // manually load image from texture atlas and add using addChild
        // ...
    }
// ...
}
```

The reference `self.childNode(withName: "dino") as? SKSpriteNode` is `nil`. How do I reference the sprite from scene editor without having to manually initialize and place it using code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure in your `GameScene.sks` that dino is indeed the `Scene` child

[image]

Then instead of creating a new `SKSpriteNode` in this line

```
private var dino: SKSpriteNode? = SKSpriteNode()
```

Make it `Optional`

```
private var dino: SKSpriteNode?
```